# Stop Kickstand on Plate Shifting into Crank Arm

Tags: kickstand

I just installed [this kickstand](https://www.amazon.ca/BV-Bicycle-Adjustable-Foldable-Kickstand/dp/B00LNLXML4/) on a bicycle with a kickstand plate. The kickstand plate has raised edges at the sides, but the mounting part of the kickstand is a bit smaller. As a result, the kickstand can shift slightly in relation to the centerline of the bike. When it shifts out, the crank arm hits the kickstand while I pedal:

[image]

Is there some way to fix the angle of the kickstand mount, either using some kind of shim or just cranking down really hard on the mounting bolt? Or should I get a different kickstand?

The bike has an aluminium frame.

Comment: Just leave the kickstand away, it's heavy and a potential source of trouble. And ff the frame is anything else than steel then anyway.especially if you want to over-tighten the bolt as you suggest. There are plenty of trees, posts, fences etc.

Comment: Can you tighten the mounting bolt more?  A large crinkle-washer between frame and stand may help, or cut some shims out of aluminium can.  Do use lots of grease to isolate steel from aluminium though.

Comment: It's an aluminum frame. I've just hand-tightened it so far.

Comment: @Carel that's thoroughly unhelpful. You don't know why the OP wants one in the first place. Have you ever tried lifting a child into a rear seat with no kickstand? Even on my tourer I miss the kickstand every time I use it for commuting.

Comment: @ChrisH *Have you ever tried lifting a child into a rear seat with no kickstand?* You actually put a child into a rear seat on a bicycle that's supported only by a kickstand?!?!  And then post *Kickstands are fiddly, and things tend to move. ..* to start an answer?  While chastising another poster?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have a double kickstand for that reason. It's locked off solid as described in my answer, but anyway the double is much more secure.  And the word *only* was yours **not mine** - it's not true for me. If you're interested the process is roughly: stand bike on kickstand.  Lift child into seat, put down without letting go. Keep arms round child & fasten seatbelt. Move one hand to saddle.  Lift handlebars, kick away stand. Get on, ride off. That's worked well for 5 years now - the one time I did it with no stand was a struggle involving standing over the top tube and twsting badly

Answer (score 4):

Kickstands are fiddly, and things tend to move unless really locked off. It's possible the bolt is loosening and the plate movement is the first symptom of loosening. To stop my bolt loosening, after adjusting everything to my liking I added a jam nut (a nut tightened against the already threaded part). This happens to be a self locking nut as that's what I had in the right size.  This is on a double kickstand similar to the one in the question.

Mine also came with a thin rubber pad to go under this plate. That helped, but when it broke I used a piece of inner tube cut to fit, which worked just as well.

Some of these plates are thicker, actually cast into a shape that should settle evenly across the chainstays. You could emulate this by attaching (probably gluing) a piece of plastic or aluminium to the plate, so that it sits between the chainstays. It would only need to be a few mm thick (around 1/4 inch) to prevent movement but would need to be nicely shaped and firmly fastened

Comment: The bolt goes into a closed tube in the kickstand, so I don't think there's anywhere to add a jam nut. I was thinking of gluing something like a nail in there?

Comment: I'm curious whether a rubber pad, steel crinkle-washer, or aluminum can shim would be most secure in this instance?

Comment: I don't think a shim that thin would do anything. The crinkle washer and rubber pad are different - the pad is to stop the plate slipping on the frame while the washer is to stop the bolt loosening. If you can degrease everything thoroughly you might get somewhere with threadlocker. Mine is subject to some unusual forces where I lock up, and the threads are quite loose, so threadlocker tends not to last, but your situation might be different

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the explanation. Is there a point in using both a crinkle washer and a rubber pad then?

Comment: It's certainly worth a try